# How do I make Sublime+LatexTools generate .bbl and include references automatically when building the pdf?

Tags: sublime-text

I am migrating to sublime and using latexTool. I think it is easy, but no solution worked for me. How I modify my Latex.sublime.build so that, when I build the pdf file, it automatically include the bibliography in a generic .bib file that I have in another folder? I don't want to compile the .bib every time separately. I am using MacOS.

Thank you guys in advance.